# Creat json data file for gallery file with php

Tags: php, json

I know this question was asked already for couple times, I've seen the answers but it already helped me a lot, but i need to solve one more problem regarding to this.
So the question is:
I need to build json file with php.
Here how looks my json file that i need:

```
{
"fashion":[
{
        "alt":"Alisa",
        "src":"img/fashion/Alisa/kubik.jpg",
        "class":"albumItem",
        "id":"FashionAlbum001",
        "itemNum":0,
        "album":[
            {
                "alt":"albumImg1",
                "src":"img/fashion/Alisa/alisa1.jpg"
            },
            {
                "alt":"albumImg1",
                "src":"img/fashion/Alisa/alisa5.jpg"
            },
            {
                "alt":"albumImg1",
                "src":"img/fashion/Alisa/alisa7.jpg"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "alt":"2-Addis",
        "src":"img/fashion/2-Addis/kubik.jpg",
        "class":"albumItem",
        "id":"FashionAlbum002",
        "itemNum":1,
        "album":[
            {
                "alt":"albumImg1",
                "src":"img/fashion/2-Addis/addis1.jpg"
            },
            {
                "alt":"albumImg4",
                "src":"img/fashion/2-Addis/addis4.jpg"
            }] } ] }
```

and so on...
I can't find out how to make a list of images inside each album
This is a php function a have

```
function buildJson(){
$json = json_encode(array(
     "Fashion" => array(
        "alt" => "Alisa",
        "src" => "img/fashion/Alisa/kubik.jpg",
        "id" => "FashionAlbum001",
        "itemNum"=>"1",
        "album"=>array(
            "src"=>"img/fashion/Alisa/alisa1.jpg",        
        ),
        array(
            "src"=>"img/fashion/Alisa/alisa5.jpg",        
        ),
        array(
            "src"=>"img/fashion/Alisa/alisa7.jpg",        
        ),

     )
));

echo $json;
```

}
but I get json like this one:

```
{
"Fashion": {
    "0": {
        "src": "img/fashion/Alisa/alisa2.jpg"
    },
    "1": {
        "src": "img/fashion/Alisa/alisa3.jpg"
    },
    "alt": "Alisa",
    "src": "img/fashion/Alisa/kubik.jpg",
    "id": "FashionAlbum001",
    "itemNum": "0",
    "album": {
        "src": "img/fashion/Alisa/alisa1.jpg"
    }
}
```

}

How is it possible to fix it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you trouble in nesting album array

fixed code

```
function buildJson(){
        $json = json_encode(
            array(
                 "Fashion" => array(
                     "alt" => "Alisa",
                     "src" => "img/fashion/Alisa/kubik.jpg",
                     "id" => "FashionAlbum001",
                     "itemNum"=>"1",

                     // nesting error here

                     "album"=> array(
                         array("src"=>"img/fashion/Alisa/alisa1.jpg"),
                         array("src"=>"img/fashion/Alisa/alisa5.jpg"),
                         array("src"=>"img/fashion/Alisa/alisa7.jpg")

                     )
                 )
            )
        );

        echo $json;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please pay more attention to the code you're writing :) Try to decode correct version of your json file and compare it to one you wrote. You should see some differences.

Your problem ir what follows after `album` key. You are assigning array with only one value to it instead of assigning array of arrays.

This is the way to go:

```
"album" => array(
    array("src" => "img/fashion/Alisa/alisa1.jpg"),
    array("src" => "img/fashion/Alisa/alisa5.jpg"),
    array("src" => "img/fashion/Alisa/alisa7.jpg"),
),
```